# startForeground() doesn't show any notification

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-notifications, foreground-service

I want to start a background service such that it stills run even application is closed,

For that, I have made the service starting sticky, and made it a process.
Than the problem persists, so I did some research and found that in recent Android devices we have to start such services in foreground :
-by using startForegroundService to start the Service, 
-and startForeground in Service's onStartCommand,
-showing a notification with a constant channel.

I did that but same problem, the notification for the foreground Service is not showing,

My service's onStartCommand :

```
  @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent,flags,startId);

        Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, RDVSearchService.class);
        intent2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent2, 0);

        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .setContentTitle("Pratikk")
                .setContentText("Subject")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ok_done)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        Notification notif;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            notif = builder.build();
        }else{
            notif = builder.getNotification();
        }

        startForeground(1234, notif);

        return START_STICKY;
    }
```

how I am starting the Service :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, RDVSearchService.class);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    context.startForegroundService(intent);
}else{
    context.startService(intent);
}
```

My service declaration in the Manifest :

```
<service
android:name=".services.RDVSearchService"
android:exported="false"
android:process=":rdv_search" />
```

Answer (score 0):

From android 8.0, must create channel.

```
    String channelId = "channelId";
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), channelId)
            .setContentTitle("Pratikk")
            .setContentText("Subject")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ok_done)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    startForeground(1234, builder.build());
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                "name", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
        channel.setDescription("description");
        channel.enableLights(false); // light
        channel.enableVibration(false); // vibration
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (manager != null) {
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }
```